# Tkinter: get StringVar from child to parent window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to python / tkinter so first of all please excuse my messy code, I hope you can make sense of it. I would like to get a username input by the user (duh) in a child window to be displayed in the parent window. However when i try and use the variable with the .get method it says it has not been defined. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    #username window
def messageWindow():
    # create child window
    win = Toplevel()
    # display message
    message = "Set Username"
    Label(win, text=message).pack()
    global vv
    vv=StringVar()
    usr= Entry(win,textvariable =vv,width=30)
    vv.set("User")
    global ss
    ss = vv.get()
    usr.pack()
    print (ss)

    Button(win, text='OK', command=win.destroy).pack()
def callback(*args):
    f = open("htfl.txt","a")
    f.write((ss)+e.get()+"\n")
    e.delete(0, 'end')
    #print (e.get())

b = Button(master, text="Send", width=10, command=callback)

b.grid(row=10,column=2)
```

Comment: do some research on global vs. local variables

Comment: I tried to set is as a global StringVar already but the error persisted.

Comment: you need to show what you tried.

Comment: Edited the post. Just declared them as global guess thats not the right approach.